# Android app only successful in one country (Playstore)

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

so released an app a few months ago. It is slowly starting to get more and more installs, not too many until now, it just passed 1000 installations. However, over 90% of new installs are from one country (Germany). It is ranked higher in PlayStore in Germany - but are there any possibilities to increase the reputation in other countries? The app isn't regional, it is an timer for perfect boiled eggs, so interests should not come from only one country... The app is available in English, German, French and Spanish.

Is there a way to increase the reputation and ranking in the Playstore in other countries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't think this quite fits in StackOverflow, as it is not code-based and could very well be opinion-based on "what works well for an audience".

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest something: try promoting your app to other countries through instagram, facebook and see if you get any new installations from the countries you chose. If so then it's not a bug, otherwise you could possibly be facing a bug somewhere in playstore or playstore is not showing your app in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only about how great your app is but also how people will take it and think of it. Even if your app is available in different languages (English, Spanish, French) which are the most spoken languages, it does not mean that it will have great success. The mindset of the people is different and differs from region to region, what people like and need in Germany does not necessarily be the same in France. Put always the user in the center and understand his **needs** so you can make the application successful.